# Android MQTT app connection issue + app UI widgets not showing

Tags: android, mqtt

I have 2 issues,

first: my android widgets/ control are not showing on the screen when the app runs

second: my app does not connect the mosquito broker

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MQTTMain">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subText"
        android:layout_width="202dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="114dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="204dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="95dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="457dp"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="262dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="405dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="278dp"
        android:text="@string/subscribe"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="404dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="241dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="277dp"
        android:text="@string/publish"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Java file ------------------------------------------------------------------

```
package com.example.MQTTMain;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class MQTTMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    MqttAndroidClient client;
    TextView subText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_m_q_t_t);

        subText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subText);
        String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
     client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), "tcp://192.168.1.7:1883",clientId);
   // client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), "192.168.1.7:1883",clientId);


        try {

            IMqttToken token = client.connect();
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Toast.makeText(MQTTMain.this,"CONNECTED!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    setSubscription();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(MQTTMain.this,"CONNECTION FAILED!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        client.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {

            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                subText.setText(new String(message.getPayload()));
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void published(View v){

        String topic = "EVENT";
        String message = "the payload";

        try {
            client.publish(topic, message.getBytes(),0,false);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Published Message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch ( MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setSubscription(){

        try{

            client.subscribe("EVENT",0);


        }catch (MqttException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void conn(View v){

        try {
            IMqttToken token = client.connect();
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Toast.makeText(MQTTMain.this,"connected!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    setSubscription();

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(MQTTMain.this,"connection failed!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void disconn(View v){

        try {
            IMqttToken token = client.disconnect();
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Toast.makeText(MQTTMain.this,"DISCONNECTED!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(MQTTMain.this,"Could not diconnect!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    }
```

My IDEA IS TO build a simple MQTT app that can publish and subscribe to a topic, but the actual broker location has to be hardcoded.

LOGS -----------------------------

```
2022-12-28 00:11:42.393 23963-23963/? I/xample.MQTTMai: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2022-12-28 00:11:42.477 23963-23963/? I/xample.MQTTMai: Unquickening 22 vdex files!
2022-12-28 00:11:42.507 23963-23963/? D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator
2022-12-28 00:11:42.507 23963-23963/? D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator - put
2022-12-28 00:11:42.572 23963-23963/com.example.MQTTMain D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication()++ app=com.example.MQTTMain
2022-12-28 00:11:42.606 23963-23963/com.example.MQTTMain D/ApplicationLoaders: Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.test.base.jar
2022-12-28 00:11:42.759 23963-23963/com.example.MQTTMain D/LoadedApk: LoadedApk::makeApplication() appContext=android.app.ContextImpl@21846dd appContext.mOpPackageName=com.example.MQTTMain appContext.mBasePackageName=com.example.MQTTMain appContext.mPackageInfo=android.app.LoadedApk@5dbb252
2022-12-28 00:11:42.759 23963-23963/com.example.MQTTMain D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-12-28 00:11:42.818 23963-23963/com.example.MQTTMain D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-12-28 00:11:42.820 23963-23963/com.example.MQTTMain D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication() -- skipGraphicsSupport=false
2022-12-28 00:11:42.827 23963-23963/com.example.MQTTMain I/ActivityThread: handleStopService: token=android.os.BinderProxy@c4c1923 not found.
```

Comment: Anything in the logs? Also you really need to include the `tcp://` on the start of the broker URI

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74903096/edit) the question to show the correct code. And you haven't answered the question about what is in the logs.

Comment: @hardillb sorry about that, you will find the corrected code in the question. Yet still, my controls don't load, and no button or text view is available on the screen.         I will add the logs too.